# PHP database results stacked ontop of each other

Tags: html, css

So my code is

```
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
    echo '<div class="leaders" style="background-color:#ada30a;">' . $row['playername']; 
    echo "<br>";
    echo $row['points']. '</div>'; 
}
```

All results (3 in total) are meant to have their own seperate div box (which they do) However, all of my boxes are stacked ontop of each other (example: http://prntscr.com/i4ygm4 (2 other boxes are stacked underneath this box)  I tried adding a margin bottom in css but it just didn't work)

The CSS code is:

```
.leaders {
    width:265px; 
    height:100px;; 
    background-color: #ee845b; 
    margin-left: 900px;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:right;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:40px;
    margin-bottom:500px;
    color:white;
    font-size: 20px;
    border:1px solid black ;
    padding-top:10px;
}
```

How do i resolve this issue?

Thank you so much. :)

Comment: This has very little to do with either php, database or mysqli.

Comment: Also, please, your CSS code should be posted as text inside the question, not as a picture.

Comment: It wasn't letting me post, I was adding 4 indents but it wasn't showing as code

Comment: Post it again, please, I'll fix that for you once you have.

Comment: .leaders {
    width:265px; 
    height:100px;; 
    background-color: #ee845b; 
    margin-left: 900px;
    padding:10px;
    text-align:right;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:40px;
    margin-bottom:500px;
    color:white;
    font-size: 20px;
    border:1px solid black ;
    padding-top:10px;
    
}

Comment: See? it wasn't hard ;)

Comment: haha, thank you for helping me

Comment: the divs stack on top of each other because of position absolute in your css file.  Change this to relative and they wont stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is caused by position absolute change it to position relative and this wont happen.

```
.leaders {
width:265px; 
height:100px;; 
background-color: #ee845b; 
margin-left: 900px;
padding:10px;
text-align:right;
position:relative;
margin-top:40px;
margin-bottom:500px;
color:white;
font-size: 20px;
border:1px solid black ;
padding-top:10px;
}
```